# How to add a custom AJAX decrease button in Woocommerce product loop?

Tags: php, wordpress, function, woocommerce, cart

I have added a plus and minus button in my Woocommerce product loop and the plus button is working fine.
Now I want to remove a product when user clicks on the minus button.

Here is the custom button for adding product plus increasing product quantity-

```
function wc_shop_demo_button() {
    global $product;
    echo '<div class="button product_type_simple add_to_cart_button ajax_add_to_cart"  data-product_id=' . $product->get_id() . ' rel="nofollow" >Plus</div>';
    echo '<div class="minus button"  data-product_id=' . $product->get_id() . ' rel="nofollow" >Minus</div>';
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'wc_shop_demo_button', 20 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button', 'wc_shop_demo_button', 20 );
```

My question is, is it possible to decrease a product amount form cart by a custom button using AJAX?
If so how?

Answer (score 0):

Display Plus & Minus Quantity Buttons in WooCommerce shop Page: Put this code in your active theme's functions.php (and remove your code).

```
 /**
 * Add quantity field on the shop page.
 */
function custom_shop_page_add_quantity_field() {
  /** @var WC_Product $product */
  $product = wc_get_product( get_the_ID() );
  if ( ! $product->is_sold_individually() && 'variable' != $product->get_type() && $product->is_purchasable() ) {
     woocommerce_quantity_input( array( 'min_value' => 1, 'max_value' => $product->backorders_allowed() ? '' : $product->get_stock_quantity() ) );
  }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'custom_shop_page_add_quantity_field', 12 );
/**
 * Add required JavaScript.
 */
function custom_shop_page_quantity_add_to_cart_handler() {
  wc_enqueue_js( '
     $(".woocommerce .products").on("click", ".quantity input", function() {
        return false;
     });
     $(".woocommerce .products").on("change input", ".quantity .qty", function() {
        var add_to_cart_button = $(this).parents( ".product" ).find(".add_to_cart_button");
        // For AJAX add-to-cart actions
        add_to_cart_button.data("quantity", $(this).val());
        // For non-AJAX add-to-cart actions
        add_to_cart_button.attr("href", "?add-to-cart=" + add_to_cart_button.attr("data-product_id") + "&quantity=" + $(this).val());
     });
     // Trigger on Enter press
     $(".woocommerce .products").on("keypress", ".quantity .qty", function(e) {
        if ((e.which||e.keyCode) === 13) {
           $( this ).parents(".product").find(".add_to_cart_button").trigger("click");
        }
     });
  ' );
}
add_action( 'init', 'custom_shop_page_quantity_add_to_cart_handler' );
```

Comment: Bro, can u just tell me how to do it in product loop?

Comment: its not working bro :( nothing happening.
I also tried by removing - 
if ( ! is_product() ) return;
But no luck

Comment: I again edited my code. It should work. I have tested it.